# Not able to open Notification bar properly when I execute this thread in the service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask, runnable

I have the following `thread` which runs in my `service` in order to prevent system `dialog` to appear. But this blocks my notification bar i.e when I drag my notification bar at half way it closes. Probably I am not writing the `thread` properly. Can some one tell me how to avoid closing of my notification bar ?

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("Service", "Started");
        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        Runnable runable = new Runnable() { 

            @Override 
            public void run() { 
                try{
                    Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
                    sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
             } 
        }; 
        handler.postDelayed(runable, 500); 
      return START_STICKY;
    }
```

I tried putting the code in `AsyncTask` as well put still the same effect with notification bar.

Comment: did you know service and activities run on same process and thread.When this service is running, i think you are doing some other tasks right?

Comment: No I am not doing any other task I created this service only for this purpose. I tried executing it inside async task since service run on the main thread but still the same effect

Comment: can you tell me the actual purpose of this service?

Comment: to block dialog box which appears when we long press the power button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the purpose of the `Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS`. This closes all the system dialogs. This includes the Notification drawer and the Recent apps.

Check the javadoc at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS

Comment: I am actually blocking the power dialog box which appears when we long press on power button. Is there any way around to achieve this

Comment: Don't think you can block this. Next to that, if you press the power button for about 20 seconds the phone will power down. So there is 'no use' to block the popup.